# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute. Strange situation

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I'm getting an error and I really don't know why Django react in a weird way.

If I write:

```
from jezyk.models import Jezyk
from pytania.models import Pytanie
from userprofile.models import UserProfile

def test_qr(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="egzamin.pdf"'

    uzyt = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('user_id')
    jez = Jezyk.objects.all()

    pytanie = Pytanie.objects.all().order_by('godzina')

    p = canvas.Canvas(response)


    for z, uzyt in enumerate(UserProfile.objects.order_by('godzina', 'jezyk_id')):

        if jez.jezyk ==  'EN' :
            for i, pytanie in enumerate(Pytanie.objects.all()):
                p.drawString(10, 400 + i*210, ' '+ pytanie.title)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'jezyk'
```

this error comes from here:

```
    if jez.jezyk ==  'EN' :
```

It is weird from me because this code works:

```
    uzyt = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('user_id')
```

Why can't get access to column jezyk from table jezyk?

In my sqlite table jezyk I have 2 columns: id and jezyk like here:

[image]

Comment: It would help if it was clear what the code intends to do.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `jez` is `QuerySet` and queryset doesn't have a property called `jezyk`:

```
jez = Jezyk.objects.all()
```

As far as I understand, you want to iterate over all user profiles and check their language settings. If so, I don't think you even need to get all `Jezyk` objects, you can probably do the following instead;

```
for z, uzyt in enumerate(UserProfile.objects.select_related('jezyk').order_by('godzina', 'jezyk_id')):
    if uzyt.jezyk.jezyk == 'EN':
        ...
```

Comment: @user3904216 you are welcome. I've updated my answer and added `select_related('jezyk')` in your queryset. By this way, `uzyt.jezyk` call in `for` loop won't hit the database.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post full traceback to your code, but one error is clear: `jez` is not a simple model object, but a `QuerySet` comprising of all SQL results, thus

```
jez = Jezyk.objects.all()
if jez.jezyk == 'EN':  # <- this fails here.
```

Maybe you instead wanted to know the language of the user: `uzyt.jezyk.jezyk`, and compare it with `'EN'`: `uzyt.jezyk.jezyk == 'EN'`?